# Remote syntactic sugar does not work for BigInt in Scala

Tags: scala, import, syntactic-sugar

I have a `SyntacticSugar` class that I use to import syntactic sugar over an elliptic curve in some files.

```
class SyntacticSugar[Point](curve : Curve[Point])
{
case class EllipticOperand (p : Point)
{
  def + (q : => Point) = curve.sum(p,q)
  def * (n : => BigInt) = curve.times(p,n)
}
implicit def PointToOperand(p : Point) = EllipticOperand(p)

case class EllipticMultiplier (n : BigInt)
{
  def * (p : => Point) = curve.times(p,n)
}
implicit def BigIntToOperand (n : BigInt) = EllipticMultiplier(n)

case class EllipticInt (n : Int)
{
  def * (p : => Point) = curve.times(p,BigInt(n))
}
implicit def IntToOperand (n : Int) = EllipticInt(n)
}
```

I use this as follow :

```
trait Curve[T] {
  def sum(p: T, q: T): T
  def times(p: T, n: Int): T
}

// dummy implementation from Jasper-M (thanks)
class PointCurve extends Curve[Point] {
  override def sum(p: Point, q: Point) = Point(p.x+q.x, p.y+q.y)
  override def times(p: Point, n: Int) = Point(p.x*n, p.y*n)
}
```

...

```
val sugar = new SyntacticSugar(curve)
import sugar._
```

The thing is that if I want to do `2 * P` where `P : Point` it doesn't work, whereas `P * 2` and `P + P` would do just fine.

The compiler says `overloaded method value * with alternatives (...) cannot be applied to (Point) a * p`

If the sugar is just pasted in the same file instead of being imported, it works perfectly.

How is that ?

Comment: Your snippets of code are not self-contained (no definitions for `Point` and `Curve`) and you don't show us the actual compiler error you get. This makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: The thing is `Point` is not defined, but I understand, sorry, I'll edit.